# GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" for servlet jsp exception javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException STATUS:500

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I started a project about Java EE, with Eclipse, following a tutorial.
During some time, all was right, I could access to my home page without any problem.

But since this afternoon i got an error when i try to load the page, refering to my HttpServlet.doGet(). Following the code and the error :

```
    package fr.tricv.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import fr.tricv.beans.DataUserBean;
import fr.tricv.utils.Definer;

public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7005932622678943062L;
    private static final String VIEW = "/WEB-INF/index.jsp";
    //public static final String VIEW_SUCCESS = "/WEB-INF/home.jsp";
    private String res = "";
    private Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<String, String>();


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VIEW).forward(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        boolean flagLogged = true;
        //HttpSession session = request.getSession();


        String email = request.getParameter(Definer.CHAMP_ID);
        String password = request.getParameter(Definer.CHAMP_MDP);
        /*
        DataUserBean user = new DataUserBean();
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword(password);

        try {
            Definer.validationEmail( user.getEmail() );
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            setError( Definer.CHAMP_MDP, e.getMessage() );
            flagLogged = false;
        }

        switch (Definer.checkUser(user)) {
            case -1: 
                res = "Utilisateur non existant ou email invalide.";
                flagLogged = false;
                break;
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            default:
                flagLogged = false;
        }
        // Process & test
        request.setAttribute("user", user);
        request.setAttribute("result", res);
        request.setAttribute("errors", errors);
        */
        if (flagLogged && errors.isEmpty()) {
            //session.setAttribute(Definer.ATT_SESSION_USER, user);
            //this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VIEW_SUCCESS).forward(request, response);
        } else {
            //session.setAttribute(Definer.ATT_SESSION_USER, null);
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VIEW).forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    private void setError(String champMdp, String message) {
        errors.put( champMdp, message );    
    }
  }
```

The JSP file :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/general.css" />
<title>Consort NT : Tri CV</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img id="nav_logo"
                    src="img/logonav.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">

        <div class="starter-template">

            <p class="lead row"></p>

            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="col-md-12">Tri CV : Login</h1>

                <form method="post" action="<c:url value="/triCV"/>"
                    class="col-md-12">

                    <fieldset class="col-md-12 login">
                        <legend>Veuillez vous connecter :</legend>
                        <div class="row login_line">
                            <div class="input-group col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 login_input">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span> <input
                                    type="text" id="email" name="email"
                                    value="<c:out value="${user.email}"/>" class="form-control"
                                    placeholder="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
                            </div>
                            <span class="error">${errors['email']}</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 separator"></div>

                        <div class="row login_line">
                            <div class="input-group col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 login_input">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"> {-} </span> <input
                                    type="password" id="password" name="password" value=""
                                    class="form-control" placeholder="MDP"
                                    aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
                            </div>
                            <span class="error">${errors['password']}</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 separator_end"></div>
                        <div class="row login_line">
                            <input type="submit"
                                class="btn btn-default col-md-offset-3 col-md-2"
                                value="Connexion" /> <input type="reset"
                                class="btn btn-default  col-md-offset-2 col-md-2"
                                value="Remise à zéro" />
                        </div>
                        <p class="${empty erreurs ? 'success' : 'error'}">${result}</p>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>


            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- 
    <p>
        <c:out value="${title}" />
        <br/>
        <c:out value="${dataBean.name}" />
        <c:set target="${dataBean}" property="name" value="CAFFREY" />
        <c:out value="${dataBean.name}" />
        <br/>Accusations : <br/>
        <c:forEach items="${dataBean.skills}" var="skill" varStatus="state">
        <div><c:out value="${state.index} : ${skill}" /></div>
        </c:forEach>
    </p>
    <p>
        <c:url value="www.google.com">
            <c:param name="dude">google</c:param>
        </c:url>
    </p>
 -->
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally the web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>TriCV</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HomeServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>fr.tricv.servlets.HomeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HomeServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/triCV</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And the error :

```
INFOS: Server startup in 574 ms
juin 15, 2016 4:22:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet jsp a lancé une exception
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.SetSupport.doEndTag(SetSupport.java:216)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fset_005f0(index_jsp.java:328)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:212)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at fr.tricv.servlets.HomeServlet.doGet(HomeServlet.java:27)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

juin 15, 2016 4:22:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [HomeServlet] in context with path [/TriCV] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException] with root cause
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.SetSupport.doEndTag(SetSupport.java:216)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fset_005f0(index_jsp.java:328)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:212)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at fr.tricv.servlets.HomeServlet.doGet(HomeServlet.java:27)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I firstly search on other posts but it appears that i didn't find the solution, a lot of posts talk about a NPE or CNF, but this is not my exception, really referring to the ".forward()"...

Can someone help me please ? :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try launching in Debug mode and breaking on `JspTagException`s. Going a few stack frames down should get you back into the JSP file itself.

Comment: It brings me on line in a file where the line "do'esn't exist" : at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)...

Comment: Can you go further down to a stack frame that references a line in the JSP file?

Comment: For the JSP file i just can see the lines in the error log : 
"org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:254)"
it refers also to the lines : 21 and 353

Comment: I guess you'll have to track down the source for the version of `org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.SetSupport` that you have and see what it's doing on line 216.

Comment: When from the console i try to access to this line eclipse indicates that "216 is not a valid line number in org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.SetSupport "

Comment: Line numbers change with code changes, so you have to find the exact version of the source that matches the version of the tag library you're using.

Comment: How do i do that ? I'm using JSTL 1.2, provided in the /WEB-INF/lib/ folder, tagged just on the index.jsp under the /WEB-INF/ foler

Comment: Google Fu. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/SetSupport.java Looks like something about your usage of the `set` tag fails its internal validation.

Comment: Why does thi error occur considering that i don't use any set tag ? The only one is commented....

Comment: That's only *client-side* commented. Any custom tags would still be processed on the server because they're not *server-side* commented out: `<%-- --%>`.

Comment: Hum right, i clearly missed this part... So the error comes from the fact that the target "dataBean" is not processed by the java handler ?

Comment: Are you sure there *is* a dataBean? Check the tag's source for why it's throwing that exception.